# save_post action not firing when save

Tags: actions, save-post

Below is my code that will take the post_id and randomly get 3 posts from the same category and store them as custom field. The code is clearly working, because when I click "New Post", I see the custom field being populated, but when I clicked "Publish" or "Save", the code below didn't get executed, from what I understand, Save_Post will be called once when creating new post and one more time when you actually save the post.

Funny thing is that the code below works in Local server, WAMP, but not on my production server, I don't know why. They all use the same plugins.

```
function update_postmeta($post_id) {
global $post;

if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
    return;
}

unset($rand_id);

$cat_id = get_the_category($post_id);

$args = array(
'showposts' => 3,
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  'cat' => $cat_id[0]->cat_ID,
  );
   $my_query = new WP_Query($args);
  while ($my_query->have_posts()) : $my_query->the_post();
    $rand_id = $rand_id.get_the_ID().',';
  endwhile; update_post_meta($post_id, 'related_id',$rand_id);
  }

add_action('save_post', 'update_postmeta');
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some errors in your code. For example, you `unset` a not defined variable. Some lines bellow you try to use again a not defined variable....maybe this is what is causing the problems.

Can you try this? (Edited, I think is better `get_posts` than `new WP_Query` in this case)

```
function wpse_update_postmeta($post_id) {

    if (defined('DOING_AUTOSAVE') && DOING_AUTOSAVE) {
        return;
    }

    $cat_id = get_the_category($post_id);
    $related_posts = array();

    if( !empty($cat_id) ) {

        $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => 3,
        'orderby' => 'rand',
        'category' => $cat_id[0]->cat_ID,
    );

    $related_posts = get_posts($args);
    }

    if( count($related_posts) > 0 ) {

        $rand_id = array();

        foreach( $related_posts as $related_post ) {
            $rand_id[] = $related_post->ID;
        }

       update_post_meta($post_id, 'related_id', implode(",", $rand_id));
       //Uncomment the next line to check if you get here
       //error_log("Hello! I'm here");

    }

}
add_action('save_post', 'wpse_update_postmeta');
```

Comment: I see, I tried your code, it is still not working. I do see the wpse_update_postmeta() fires when I click the "New Post", but it doesn't fire again when I click "Publish".

Comment: I've tested the code and it works when **Publish** a new post or **Update** an old post. That is, every time the **Save** event occurs. Maybe your problem is related with other code in your plugin/theme or with other plugins you may be using. [Use error_log to debug what is happing inside youw `save_post` hook](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7878279/how-to-debug-save-post-actions-in-wordpress).

Comment: I've read againg your question and you say "The code is clearly working, because when I click "New Post", I see the custom field being populated". Can you explain what do you mean? The population of fields is not done by the `save_post` hook; normally it is done via `add_meta_box` or similar.

Comment: I will try to debug it with error_log. save_post hook is called twice when you create new content, one when you click on "New Post", another when you "Save/Publish". When I click the "New Post", I see the Related_ID field being populated, because of the add_action('save_post','wpse_update_postmeta');, it was suppose to call the wpse_update_postmeta function one more time when I "Save/Publish", but it is not doing it.

Comment: You are wrong. When you click on "New Post" the `save_post` hook is not called. I assume that the Related_ID field is a custom field displayed in a custom meta box; the custom field is normally rendered and populated via [`add_meta_box`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_meta_box) function and introduced in a custom meta box via [`add_meta_boxes`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/add_meta_boxes) action. Then, the field is saved via [`save_post`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post) action.

Comment: it is not being documented, but save_post is actually being called more than 1 time when you create/save post. Anyway, I believe I narrow down the problem, it might the NEXT SCRIPT AUTO POST Plugin.

Comment: Maybe are you talking about a old bug already fixed? https://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/12969

Comment: Thank you. I am afraid the "problem/bug" is not fixed. if you tried the above code in your test wordpress site, install the "advanced custom fields" plugin, and create a custom field named "related_id", then go and click on "New Post", you will see that the above code executed, and it will execute one more  time when you click "Save/Publish"

Comment: the `save_post` action hook is called any time a saving proccess runs, that is when you click save/publish/update and also during auto-saving. If you think there is bug you should report it.